# css select all elements that match specific class combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have these divs in my html:

```
<div id="div1" class="class1 aa class2 bb class3 cc class4 dd class5 ee"></div>
<div id="div2" class="class1 ff class2 gg class3 hh class4 ii class5 jj"></div>
<div id="div3" class="class1 aa class2 bb class3 mm class4 nn class5 oo"></div>
```

And I have the following strings:

```
var string1 = "class1 class2 class3 class4 class5";
var string2 = "aa class2 class3 class4 class5";
var string3 = "ff gg hh ii jj";
var string4 = "aa bb class3 class4 class5";
```

Ok so I'm trying to create a Jquery selector that gets one of the strings and selects as follow:

```
string1 //should select all 3 divs
string2 //should select div1 and div3
string3 //should select div2
string4 //should select div1 and div3
```

So the idea is that the selector gets the string and if all classes from the given string(5 classes) MATCH the div classes, the div gets selected.I have tried something like this but didint work.

```
$('div[class=' + stringnumber + ']').css(dosomething);
```

Comment: if you split the strings via the space, joined by `.` instead, you could just select `$('"div."+string')` should do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you don't actually want to match the entire `class` attribute string value, use a multi-class selector.

```
var string1 = '.class1.class2.class3.class4.class5';

$('div' + string1).css(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 //should select all 3 divs 
string2 //should select div1 and div3 
string3 //should select div2 
string4 //should select div1 and div3 probably mistake. Do you mean div1 and div2?
```

`string1` is obvious: `$('.class1')`.
`string2`: `$('.aa')`
`string3`: `$('.ff')`
`string4`: `$('.class1:not(.nn)')` for div1 and div2